Javascript for Interactive stamps in Bluebeam
I have an interactive stamps in Adobe Acrobat and Bluebeam.
I'm able to achieve what I want in Adobe but it doesn't work in Bluebeam.
I'm trying to display or hide a radio button group (P2-Recommandation) but this doesn't work :
this.getField("P2-Recommandation").display = display.hidden
this.getField("P2-Recommandation").display = display.visible

Thank you
I found an unofficial Bluebeam API reference file and "display" does exist, except it's written "dislpay" in the file, I guess it's a syntax error. I tried just in case but it's doesn't work either way.
I also try to use "display.hidden" on a text field just in case radio button group work differently but the text field was not being hide too.
I contact the support of Bluebeam but there is not an expert in Javascript that could help me.
I'm stuck with that!
